# Constants in LESS and Typescript

Tags: less, constants, typescript

Sometimes I want to define a constant, which is to be used in both LESS and Typescript. What is the best way for achieving that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you have any common ground here - unless you are going to parse the variable by reading one language from the other.

You could use a server-side language to inject the constant into both a LESS file and a TypeScript file, but this could be overkill.

One possible solution would be to detect the value that was used in the LESS file by inspecting the DOM result, for example if you had a width in LESS defined as a constant, you could inspect the width of the element in TypeScript to get the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Unfortunately "server-side is no solution, as in my case LESS and Typescript do not exist on the server (only within VS2012). Reading the width will work for numeric values. For string values, maybe I can put an arbitrary string into the "font-family" and then read it from Javascript. I will try.

Comment: Or use a CSS class that you can use in both LESS and TypeScript.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure whether I understand your last remark correctly. Basically the problem is: there is a constant TIME with a value of "3s" and I want to use that value in both LESS and Typescript. LESS is easy, just declare (at)TIME:3s. Now I want to use (at)TIME in Javacript. The idea is to define a class .dummy{font-family:"(at){TIME}"}. Then in Javascript I create a new DOM element, asssign that class, and access the font-family property. It seems to work. But is it safe to do so? Will all browsers allow arbitrary values in that property?

Comment: I don't think you would get it back out of a font-family declaration - browsers are a bit funny with that. You could put the `3` into an arbitrary numeric property, but not `3s`, which would only really be seen in real life against something like `transition-duration`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tCfp7/

Comment: The content property seems to be an ideal property for storing a constant's value. See http://jsfiddle.net/mgs_jsfiddle/VyM9z/.

Comment: Yes - check it in the browsers you are supporting, but that could be an ideal place.

Answer (score 0):

The below has not been tested.  If I decide to do this in my own work then I'll check it.

Put your constants in a standalone JavaScript file, in an object constants.js:

```
export const shareWithLess = {
    constantName: '400px'
};
```

Write a little node script to generate a constants file for LESS:

```
const constants = require('./constants.js');
for (const [name, value] of Object.entries(constants) {
    if (typeof value === 'number')
        console.log(`@${name}: @{value};`);
    else if (typeof value === 'string')
        console.log(`@${name}: '@{value}';`);
    else
        throw new Error(`Unexpected type for value of '${name}' in constants.js`);
}
```

and run it like this:

```
node generateConstants.js >./constants.less
```

which would then contain

```
@constantName: 400px;
```

Worrying about quotes and generating a .d.ts is left as an exercise for the reader.